# Can I have Visual Studio stop on unhandled exceptions inside Task code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

Visual Studio has a certain feature that makes debugging unhandled exceptions a lot easier: it stops on the offending line of code and shows the exception.

It seems that the `Task` class is designed in such a way that this feature is always suppressed: it catches every exception, and then rethrows a different exception when the task is `Wait`ed or finalized.

I know I can have it stop on first-chance exceptions, but this doesn't always help: imagine that a number of handled exceptions of the same type occur prior to the unhandled one. In this case VS will stop on every non-problematic exception in addition to the one that actually causes the problem.

Another alternative is even less acceptable: just looking at the stack trace of the `InnerException`: this means that while I know which line caused the exception, I cannot access any of its local state, like I could if the program was actually stopped there.

Can I somehow get the best of both worlds, using the `Task` class but not having to live with the degraded exception debugging feature set?

---

Bonus question: does this mean that a null reference exception inside an `await` block will not cause Visual Studio to stop right there, but will instead stop somewhere else altogether?

Comment: The private Task.Execute() method contains the catch everything statement.  HandleException and AddException after that.  Everything is private and non-virtual.

Comment: @HansPassant if you wish to post that as an answer (implying that this is impossible, basically), I will eventually accept it in the absence of better answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Task` type does wrap all exceptions into an `AggregateException`. However, if you're using the `async`/`await` functionality, then when you `await` a `Task`, the inner exception is unwrapped and re-thrown, preserving the original stack trace.

VS11 will have better `async` debugging support, but I don't think it's possible to go as far as what you're hoping. `Task` is all about concurrent and asynchronous code, and that's why I don't think this will ever work.

Consider, for example, if you have a `Task` running on a thread pool thread that you're going to `await`. You can `await` it in a `try` block to catch an exception from the `Task`... or you can `await` it outside of a `try` block, leaving the `Task`'s exception to be unhandled.

The point with that example is that when the exception is thrown, the debugger *doesn't know* if the exception *will be* unhandled. With synchronous code, as soon as the exception is thrown, the stack is checked - and if it's unhandled, the debugger knows it is unhandled and can take special action right away (before the stack is even unwound).

So, I don't think it's possible to do what you want. You can get pretty close with IntelliTrace, though (only in VS Ultimate).

Comment: I understand that it's caught because one can't know whether something will want to look at it _outside_ the task. But I wouldn't say what I want is _fundamentally_ impossible; it's just not implemented. There's no reason why Task couldn't have a `TaskCreationOption.LeaveExceptionsAlone`. `async` would not specify that option to get the features it wants; I would specify it to get the features I want. Alas, that's not part of the current implementation.